# Running Java application as a service

Tags: java, command-line, jboss

We have a java application that's essentially a long running process. It's deployed on JBoss 6.1. We have to start it by going to the url `http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8080/MyApp/Monitor`

Is there a way we could run it as a service via the cli with some ability to start / stop / restart as needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the only application running on the JBoss instance, you could configure your JBoss to automatically start you application when it starts and then follow the steps in http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossSystemService to run JBoss as a service.

If you have other applications on the JBoss instance or you want to start/stop only the application and not the whole server, you could write a Java application that connects to your JBoss instance remotely using Java Management Extensions and use the JMX Beans provided by JBoss to start/stop your application. More about JBoss JMX interface can be found in http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r2/html/ch2.chapter.html I know this is of JBoss 4 but I don't think they dropped JMX support in newer versions.

Comment: How do I configure JBoss instance to start my application when JBoss is started? Sorry, I'm new to Java. Just need to get this app deployed right.

Comment: If you are using the default server configuration JBoss should automatically deploy all applications in the deploy directory. How deployment can be achieved can be found here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossDeploy

Comment: It does deploy it, but I have to navigate to a URL to actually run the application.

Comment: Is your application a web application? I can't find the source at the moment but I read in the JBoss docs that it should start deployed webapps automatically. :/

Answer (score 0):

Make it a console application?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    doStuffThatMyAppMonitorNormallyDoes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire a call to your application directly from the console using the `java` command.

*Example*:

```
public class MonitorService{

 ..

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-start")
  {
    //Do start routine
  }
  else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-stop")
  {
    //Do stop routine
  }
 }

 ...

}
```

Run the program as the follows.

```
Java MonitorService -start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it to windows/unix service using

[java service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Apache Commons Daemon (or maybe YAJSW) to create your own wrapper controller class.  An example of this is [shown here](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Daemon).   The wrapper controller extends the Daemon class of Commons-Daemon and it could be ran on the command line in the form of :

```
java -cp . WrapperController.class -windowsStop
java -cp . WrapperController.class -windowsStart
java -cp . WrapperController.class -verify
```

You could also of course, extend the example to have its own SysTray object.   You could also implement your controller class as a Beanshell script so that it need not be a pre-compiled class to run.